# Outgoing email not in gitlab docker

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have a gitlab docker successfully running using the docker registry.  I followed the steps mentioned at https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html

The issue is, outgoing emails are not working.  i.e., if I signup a user or reset his password, no emails are sent.

I have installed gitlab as standalone app in the past and do not remember configuring anything extra to enable gitlab to send mails out.

What is missing in docker image and how to fix that?